# Providing include directory outside source folder for static library users

Tags: cmake

I am developing a simple static C library for learning purposes using cmake.
Some projects like [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) provide an `include` folder on the root, so library users can copy it and use it as an include directory.

In my library, I want to have an `include` folder on the root, so when I use the library on other projects, I can just copy this folder and set it as an include directory.

Here is a simplified folder structure of my library:

```
include
+--mylib.h

src
+--myheader.h
+--mysource.c
+--CMakeLists.txt

CmakeLists.txt
```

The `src` folder has my headers and implementation files, and a `CMakeLists.txt` for building a static library out of `mysource.c`.

The CMakeLists on the root folder just sets the project and adds `src` as a subdirectory.

I want the `mylib.h` file to have a `#include <myheader.h>`.

**Here's a detour to talk about how I want to use it when it's done.**

The idea is that when using the lib on another project, I can have something like this:

```
deps
+--include
   +--mylib.h

src
+--main.c
```

And in the `main.c` file, include `mylib.h` and use what's defined on `myheader.h`
**Here the detour ends, and I'm talking about my actual lib project again.**

How can I achieve this using cmake? As far as I know, the `mylib.h` file needs to know it's including files from the `src` diretory, but I see no way of setting that, as for exemple in GLFW this directory does not have a CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: `is including files from the source folder?` - how do you tell cmake to include files from the `include` folder?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking, is the `src` folder **your** source folder? Or the `src` folder in GLFW? If `mylib.h` is including files from the `src` folder, how is `mylib.h` included in the CMake project in the first place? It may help to provide your example CMake code..

Comment: Sorry about that, the question was quite confusing. I edited it so hopefully it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gonna quess that this is a design issue since it would make sense to you if you would have installed the library to a system before you tried to use it. That is, not using add_subdirectory() but find_library() at usage.

First, if you are using a external library, but not installing it, you would include all files in you deps-folder. All files then include source-files and so on and will be compiled besides you main.c. This is done with add_subdirectory(deps/MyLib) and later also included in you main-project.

Example:

```
add_subdirectory(deps/MyLib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE MyLib)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE MyLib)
```

If you do not want to compile it all the time, then you must instruct cmake where it can find headers and library-files. Preferred way is to use find_library() which does some magic for you. Since you do not mention any installation i will assume that it does not exist and your only option is then to use add_subdirectory().

> "I can just copy this folder and set it as an include directory."

CMake wants to handle these things for you so you should never copy headers around. You should either use add_subdirectory() to include a project/headers or make use of the find_library() which make sure you find where the headers are in the system.

I suggest that you push yourself to learn howto install a library into a system and how to utilize it later, but only by using find_library(). Then the library will be global for all projects and also not duplicated.

Adding some kind of psudo-code in hope it all makes more sense. Although it is around add_subdirectory() since the code for installing is quite large unfortunately.

CMakeLists.txt for main.c

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(MyLibTest)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.c
)

add_subdirectory(external/MyLib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE MyLib)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE MyLib)
```

CMakeLists.txt for library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(MyLib)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    src/MyLib.c
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC 
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>    
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)
```

The structure for the project would then be:

```
/
  external/MyLib
  external/MyLib/src
    MyLib.c
  external/MyLib/include
    MyLib.h
  src
    main.c
  CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: You're right, I should have put more thought (and more attention) into this. GLFW's global header doesn't include any files, it defines what it wants to expose like any other header (this was a "wait a minute, it wouldn't work if it was including files from a folder I don't have" moment).

I will look into learning about how to install the lib and give this another go, the pseudo-code will be helpful.

Thanks a lot, ~and sorry for asking before putting a bit more thought into it~.

Comment: @ViniciusLambardozzi: Dont be too hard on yourself :). Its always worth asking questions as long as you grow with them. I wouldnt answer if i didnt believe that you would ;)